# I am trying to convert an array method to an ArrayList method

Tags: java

My method is trying to find a certain card with a suit and a value previously described in enums.
My original code is:

```
public int find(Suit s, Value v) {

    for(int i=0; i<numCards; i++) {
        if(cards[i].getSuit() == s && cards[i].getValue() == v) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

cards was an array and I've already converted it to an array, but how do I modify the code to apply to an ArrayList? Is there a method I should be using or would HashTables help me?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this (assuming it's cards that is the arraylist):

```
 public int find(Suit s, Value v) {
    for(int i=0; i<cards.size(); i++) {
       if(cards.get(i).getSuit()==s && cards.get(i).getValue()==v) {
             return i;
            }
        }
          return -1;
   }
```

This should traverse through every element in the `ArrayList` for cards

Comment: I had switched the square brackets to normal ones but I didn't think about adding another get method. Anyway it compiled (don't know if it works yet) but I'll let you know, Thank you!

Comment: get() is a method of an ArrayList to return the i-th element, try googling them

Comment: I will, I've only recently learned about ArrayList so I'm trying to get used to them

Answer (score 1):

You should really never use arrays. They are inherently less flexible and reliable.

You should have a Card class like this:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  public int compareTo(Card other) { return this.value - other.value;}
}
```

Then have

```
List<Card> cards;
```

Notice I am specifying ArrayList or LinkedList .. just List.

Then you can just use

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(cards,new Card(...));
```

Implementing a for loop is just not the way to go.